# Finding equal row and column between 2 arrays

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I am trying to write function in C that gets two 2-dimensional arrays, then it checks if there is an equal column in array 2 for every row in array 1.
I need to print every time there is a match, and the row number in array 1 that had most matches in array 2.

It must be done with simple arrays (`arr[][m]` for example).
My code that does not work:

```
void main()
{
    int i, j,k, flag = 0,count = 0,max_r,max = 0;
    int arr[M][M] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, arr1[M][M]={4,4,6,5,5,4,8,6,9};
    i = 0;
    while (i < M)
    {
        j = 0;
        k = 0;
        while (j < M)
        {
            if (arr[i][j] == arr1[j][k])
                flag = 1;
            else
                flag = 0;
            j++;                
            if (j == M)
            {
                if (flag == 1)
                {
                    printf("row %d in arr eqauls to calm %d in arr1\n", i+1, k+1);
                    count++;
                }
                k++;
                k = 0;
            }
        }
        if (count > max)
        {   
            max = count;
            max_r = i;
        }
        count = 0;
        i++;
    }
    printf("the max row is:%d\n", max_r+1);
    getche();
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your program should do, an what it is doing instead.

Comment: It seems that you have some trouble with your array declaration... http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/113489-initializing-2d-array-c.html

Comment: the program needs to print every time a column in array 2 equals to row in array 1.in the end to print number of row in array 1 that had most matches of columns in array 2.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Your code is nearly an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but there are details like `enum { M = 3 };` (or did you use `#define M 3`) missing. Also missing is an explanation of what is going wrong and how you're running into problems. Your `while` loops should probably be `for` loops; it's cleaner to keep the loop controls at the top of the loop. You should probably set `flag` to 1 before the inner loop and set it to 0 if there's a mismatch, and `break` the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working version.  Before we get to that some tips:

Don't use:

```
int i,j;
```

It's legal but less clear/flexible than:

```
int i;
int j;
```

Use more *descriptive* names:  Instead of `i` use a slightly longer name (e.g. `arridx` which is short for: `arr`'s index variable).  Or `colno` (column number) instead of `k`.  This may seem trivial, but it can really help clarify things for you.  I know that's what many courses/books teach, but, IMO, it leads to more grief

Use `for` loops for iteration when using index variables.  It simplifies things.

Proper/clean indentation allows you to see logic errors more quickly.

Separate sections of code vertically with a blank line.

Use comments liberally.  Good comments should show *intent* or "the what".  The code is "the how".  The comments should be readable enough that a lay person can get some semblance of what's going on, even if they can't read the code itself.  For example:

```
// initialize the defense subsystem before use
flak_init();
```

Here is the working version.  I apologize for the extensive gratuitous style cleanup but it was the only way [for me] to get to a working version from your code.  There were too many errors to explain in words or hints.  This version is simpler and fixes the bugs.  Compare against your version.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define WIDTH       9                   // number of elements in a line

// this was "arr"
#define ALINE       1                   // number of lines
int alist[ALINE][WIDTH] = {
    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }
    // add new lines here (and adjust ALINE)
};

// this was "arr1"
#define BLINE       1                   // number of lines
int blist[BLINE][WIDTH] = {
    { 4, 4, 6, 5, 5, 4, 8, 6, 9 }
    // add new lines here (and adjust BLINE)
};

int
main()
{
    int aline;
    int bline;
    int colno;
    int count;
    int max_aline = 0;
    int max_count = 0;

    // loop through all lines of alist
    for (aline = 0;  aline < ALINE;  ++aline) {
        // loop through all lines of blist
        for (bline = 0;  bline < BLINE;  ++bline) {
            count = 0;

            // loop through all columns of each line
            // if a given column should match, print a message and
            // increase the count of the number of column matches in the
            // current line
            for (colno = 0;  colno < WIDTH;  ++colno) {
                if (alist[aline][colno] == blist[bline][colno]) {
                    printf("row %d in alist equals column %d in blist\n",
                        aline + 1,colno + 1);
                    count++;
                }
            }

            // record a new maximum and remember the line number of alist
            if (count > max_count) {
                max_count = count;
                max_aline = aline;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("the max row is:%d\n",max_aline + 1);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```